# egrep in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

Can anyone please help here. If not feasible with egrep, other suggestions too would be highly appreciated.

I am trying to write an egrep expression to grep ORA-00942 with "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75", when it is in the next line of "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75" string. However ORA-00942 in any other line in the file should be ignored. ORA-00942 has to be grepped only when its in the next line followed by "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75".

```
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"
ORA-00942:     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< should be grepped along with "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"

ORA-00490: error text is xyz
ORA-00942:   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this should be ignored
```

Comment: I know that `sed` is better in this kind of tasks, have you looked into it?

Comment: Thanks Yaron. No,i am very new to shell scripting. Do you have any idea of sed expression for this ?

Comment: sed and grep are both the wrong tools to use for anything that involves searching across multiple lines of input. Just use awk (or if you don't mind non-standard tools there's perl, ruby, python, etc.)

Comment: @Ed Morton: There is a natural solution with grep that is working:
`grep -A1 UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 inputfile | grep -B1 ORA-00942`

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi That's not a natural solution with grep, it's a solution with 2 greps and a shell pipe and it'll fail (i.e. produce output when it shouldn't) when ORA-00942 appears on the same line as UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with grep.

```
grep -A1 UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 inputfile | grep -B1 ORA-00942
```

You can do it with two piece of grep. Because grep has a handy
option `-An` and `-Bn`.

e.g.:
`grep UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 -A3 inputfile`

Print 3 lines of trailing context after matching lines
and -Bn option is:
Print n lines of leading context before matching lines.
pls read in `man grep`.

In this answer I piped the first grep to the 2nd. But you can
do it in two steps also with a tmp_file instead of pipe to see how works grep commands.

```
grep -A1 UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 inputfile >tmp_file
grep -B1 ORA-00942 tmp_file
```

And you can give the matching more precisely if you need it.
e.g.:

```
grep -A1 -w UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 inputfile | grep -B1 -w ^ORA-00942
```

Comment: That's not looking for `ORA-00942 has to be grepped only when its in the next line followed by "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"` and so will fail (i.e. produce output when it shouldn't) when `ORA-00942` appears on **the same line** as `UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75`. Try `echo 'ORA-00942 foo UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75' | grep -A1 UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75 | grep -B1 ORA-00942`.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/"UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"/{N;/\n.*ORA-00942/p;D}'
```

Comment: You should mention which sed version(s) will work with that expression. With OSX/BSD sed it fails with `sed: 1: "/"UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"/ ...": extra characters at the end of D command`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl solution. It's not as short as the sed answer, but I find it more readable:

```
perl -nle 'print if (/^ORA-00942/ && $wanted); if (/UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75/) {$wanted=1} else {$wanted=0}' /your/file
```

Or a slightly shorter version:

```
perl -nle 'print if (/^ORA-00942/ && $wanted); $wanted=(/UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75/ ? 1 : 0)' /your/file
```

This sets a `$wanted` flag to true if the current line contains "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75", or to false if it doesn't.

This prints only lines that start with "ORA-00942", and only when `$wanted` is true.

If you also want to print the previous line, use [Ed Morton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419162/111036) instead, which prints both.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/ORA-00942/ && (p ~ /UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75/){print p ORS $0} {p=$0}' file
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"
ORA-00942:     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< should be grepped along with "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise a combination of `grep` and `awk`:

You can use `grep -n` in order to get the lines, containing "ORA-00942", you get something like:

```
2:line_2 contains ORA-00942
8:line_5 contains ORA-00942
```

From that, using `awk` with ':' as a field separator, you can get the line numbers which contain "ORA-00942" (`[2,8]`).

You can then use `grep -n` in order the lines, containing "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75", which might be something like:

```
4:line_4 contains UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75
7:line_7 contains UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75
```

Using `awk` again you get the line numbers which contain "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75" (`[4,7]`).

From there you process both lists of line numbers in order to get the matching ones.

*Tips and tricks*: instead of keeping the lines, containing "UTL_RECOMP_SLAVE_75", you take the line numbers plus one (instead of `[4,7]` you have `[5,8]`), it might prove easier to find two lists with the same numbers than to check on the "plus one" values.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk.